# She will have been working vs she will be working

Tags: meaning, tense

> By ten o'clock, she will have been typing for three hours

> By ten o'clock, she will be typing for three hours

First one is Future Perfect Continues
Second is Future Continues

I can't understand the difference between these two.

Answer (score 2):

> By ten o'clock , she will have been typing for three hours

At ten o'clock, she will have three hours of typing work behind her.

> By ten o'clock , she will be typing for three hours

No correct sentence because Future Continuous tells about what happens exactly at the referenced time in the future. It cannot be used to tell about actions which have started before the referenced time in the future and last until the referenced time.

Comment: I agree. For example, you might say "By ten o'clock, she will be typing.", describing an action that may have started before ten o'clock, but will still be going on at ten.

Comment: "At ten o'clock, she will have three hours of typing work behind her."  In other words, she started typing at seven o'clock  (unless she took a break).

Answer (score 1):

> By ten o'clock, she will have been typing for three hours

This means she started/will start typing at 7:00 and continue typing through 10:00.

> By ten o'clock, she will be typing for three hours

This is an odd sentence, probably bad grammar. If it has any meaning, it means that she has a task of "three hours of typing" to do, and at 10:00 she will be doing it.